# Can't start process in erlang node

Tags: erlang

I have two erlang nodes, node01 is `'vm01@192.168.146.128'`, node02 is `'vm02@192.168.146.128'`. I want to start one process on node01 by using `spawn(Node, Mod, Fun, Args)` on node02, but I always get useless pid.

Node connection is ok:

```
(vm02@192.168.146.128)14> net_adm:ping('vm01@192.168.146.128').
pong
```

Module is in the path of node01 and node02:

```
(vm01@192.168.146.128)7> m(remote_process).
Module: remote_process
MD5: 99784aa56b4feb2f5feed49314940e50
Compiled: No compile time info available
Object file: /src/remote_process.beam
Compiler options:  []
Exports: 
         init/1
         module_info/0
         module_info/1
         start/0
ok
```

---

```
(vm02@192.168.146.128)20> m(remote_process).
Module: remote_process
MD5: 99784aa56b4feb2f5feed49314940e50
Compiled: No compile time info available
Object file: /src/remote_process.beam
Compiler options:  []
Exports: 
         init/1
         module_info/0
         module_info/1
         start/0
ok
```

However, the spawn is not successful:

```
(vm02@192.168.146.128)21> spawn('vm01@192.168.146.128', remote_process, start, []). 
I'm on node 'vm01@192.168.146.128'
<9981.89.0>
My pid is <9981.90.0>

(vm01@192.168.146.128)8> whereis(remote_process).
undefined
```

The process is able to run on local node:

```
(vm02@192.168.146.128)18> remote_process:start().
I'm on node 'vm02@192.168.146.128'
My pid is <0.108.0>
{ok,<0.108.0>}

(vm02@192.168.146.128)24> whereis(remote_process).
<0.115.0>
```

But it fails on remote node. Can anyone give me some idea?

Here is the source code remote_process.erl:

```
-module(remote_process).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start/0, init/1]).

start() ->
    {ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_link({global, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []),
    {ok, Pid}.

init([]) ->
    io:format("I'm on node ~p~n", [node()]),
    io:format("My pid is ~p~n", [self()]),
    {ok, {{one_for_one, 1, 5}, []}}.
```

Comment: Please show the source for echo_server. Would also be helpful to see the working version on local compared to the non-working version on remove.

Comment: @StevePallen Hi, I've updated my source code and put more details on it. Please have a look.

Comment: You are starting remote_process with local atom. Try global

Comment: @StevePallen Still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a global registration for your process, it is necessary for your purpose. The function to retrieve it is `global:whereis_name(remote_process)`.

**Edit :** It works if

- the 2 nodes are connected (check with nodes())
- the process is registered with the global module
- the process is still alive

if any of these conditions is not satisfied you will get `undefined`

[image]

**Edit 2:** start node 1 with : `werl -sname p1` and type in the shell :

```
(p1@W7FRR00423L)1> c(remote_process).
{ok,remote_process}
(p1@W7FRR00423L)2> remote_process:start().
I'm on node p1@W7FRR00423L
My pid is <0.69.0>
{ok,<0.69.0>}
(p1@W7FRR00423L)3> global:whereis_name(remote_process).
<0.69.0>
(p1@W7FRR00423L)4>
```

then start a second node with `werl - sname p2` and type in the shell (it is ok to connect the second node later, the global registration is "updated" when necessary):

```
(p2@W7FRR00423L)1> net_kernel:connect_node(p1@W7FRR00423L).
true
(p2@W7FRR00423L)2> nodes().
[p1@W7FRR00423L]
(p2@W7FRR00423L)3> global:whereis_name(remote_process).
<7080.69.0>
(p2@W7FRR00423L)4> 
(p2@W7FRR00423L)4>
```

**Edit 3:**

In your test you are spawning a process `P1` on the remote node which executes the function `remote_process:start/0`.

This function calls `supervisor:start_link/3` which basically spawns a new supervisor process `P2` and links itself to it. after this, `P1` has nothing to do anymore so it dies, causing the linked process `P2` to die too and you get an `undefined` reply to the `global:whereis_name` call.

In my test, I start the process from the shell of the remote node; the shell does not die after I evaluate `remote_process:start/0`, so the supervisor process does not die and `global:whereis_name` find the requested pid.

If you want that the supervisor survive to the call, you need an intermediate process that will be spawned without link, so it will not die with its parent. I give you a small example based on your code:

```
-module(remote_process).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start/0, init/1,local_spawn/0,remote_start/1]).

remote_start(Node) ->
    spawn(Node,?MODULE,local_spawn,[]).

local_spawn() ->
    % spawn without link so start_wait_stop will survive to
    % the death of local_spawn process
    spawn(fun start_wait_stop/0).

start_wait_stop() ->
    start(),
    receive
        stop -> ok
    end.

start() ->
    io:format("start (~p)~n",[self()]),
    {ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_link({global, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []),
    {ok, Pid}.

init([]) ->
    io:format("I'm on node ~p~n", [node()]),
    io:format("My pid is ~p~n", [self()]),
    {ok, {{one_for_one, 1, 5}, []}}.
```

in the shell you get in node 1

```
(p1@W7FRR00423L)1> net_kernel:connect_node(p2@W7FRR00423L).
true
(p1@W7FRR00423L)2> c(remote_process).
{ok,remote_process}
(p1@W7FRR00423L)3> global:whereis_name(remote_process).
undefined
(p1@W7FRR00423L)4> remote_process:remote_start(p2@W7FRR00423L).
<7080.68.0>
start (<7080.69.0>)
I'm on node p2@W7FRR00423L
My pid is <7080.70.0>
(p1@W7FRR00423L)5> global:whereis_name(remote_process).        
<7080.70.0>
(p1@W7FRR00423L)6> global:whereis_name(remote_process).
undefined
```

and in node 2

```
(p2@W7FRR00423L)1> global:registered_names(). % before step 4
[]
(p2@W7FRR00423L)2> global:registered_names(). % after step 4
[remote_process]
(p2@W7FRR00423L)3> rp(processes()).
[<0.0.0>,<0.1.0>,<0.4.0>,<0.30.0>,<0.31.0>,<0.33.0>,
 <0.34.0>,<0.35.0>,<0.36.0>,<0.37.0>,<0.38.0>,<0.39.0>,
 <0.40.0>,<0.41.0>,<0.42.0>,<0.43.0>,<0.44.0>,<0.45.0>,
 <0.46.0>,<0.47.0>,<0.48.0>,<0.49.0>,<0.50.0>,<0.51.0>,
 <0.52.0>,<0.53.0>,<0.54.0>,<0.55.0>,<0.56.0>,<0.57.0>,
 <0.58.0>,<0.62.0>,<0.64.0>,<0.69.0>,<0.70.0>]
ok
(p2@W7FRR00423L)4> pid(0,69,0) ! stop. % between steps 5 and 6
stop
(p2@W7FRR00423L)5> global:registered_names().
[]
```

Comment: I still got undefined result when I use global:whereis_name(remote_process).

Comment: check with the small sequence in the shell if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, however, I still can't figure out why my code can't work. As shown in my description, two nodes are already connected, and I use {global, remote_process} in my code, but when I run spawn/4, it fails. I can event start the process on the local node, but it is not my scenario. I want one node to start one process in another node.

Comment: I have tried your code, using 2 nodes on the same PC, and it works fine. Are you trying something different?

Comment: Is my Erlang broken or some firewall stuff prevent me from doing that?